# Pig: How to save relation when "Scalar has more than two rows in the output"

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

So, I'm processing a log file with http traffic entries. I'm trying to determine the number of records for every hour of the day for every status code.
So, my idea output, would be something like this:

```
0 (200, 234) (201, 100) (404, 5553)
1 (200, 2234) (201, 1100) (404, 53)
....
```

I have the following transformations in place:

```
e1 = group LINES BY (hour, statusCode);
e2 = foreach e1 generate group.hour, group.statusCode, COUNT(LINES);
e3 = group e2 by hour;
e4 = foreach e3 {
    statusCount = foreach e2 generate statusCode, $2;
    generate e3.group, statusCount;
};
```

And when I try to "dump e4" I get the following error message:

> Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st :
>   (0,{(0,000,1),(0,200,951),(0,206,1),(0,302,4),(0,304,20),(0,403,118),(0,500,6)}),
>   2nd
>   :(1,{(1,200,781),(1,301,1),(1,304,14),(1,400,1),(1,403,111),(1,502,12)})

As you can see, the values are there, I just need to save them... but how? I tried doing a

```
e5 = foreach e4 generate group, statusCount;
```

But I get the same output. I know I'm missing something basic, but I can't figure out what..

--

Comment: what is the schema of LINES?

Comment: LINES is an alias. You need to count the number of rows in a column, not in the relation LINES.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input data?. In your final output "0 (200, 234) (201, 100) (404, 5553)" i assume 0 refer to time, 200,201,401 refer to error code and 234,100,5553 refer to total count of the corresponding error code. Is this right?

Comment: @SivasakthiJayaraman yes you're right.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily solve this problem but the challenge will be in the output format as you mentioned.

**Option1:**
In case of standard pig, you will always get the below output format (ie bag will be enclosed your output).

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage() AS (hour:int, statusCode:chararray);
B = GROUP A BY (hour,statusCode);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (hour,statusCode),COUNT($1) AS cnt;
D = GROUP C BY hour;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE group,C.(statusCode,cnt);
STORE E INTO 'output' USING PigStorage();
```

**Output:**

```
0   {(302,2),(304,3),(403,1),(500,1)}
1   {(200,1),(301,1),(304,2),(400,1),(403,1),(502,5)}
```

**Option2:**
If you want to achieve the output format as you mentioned then you have to use Custom UDF `BagToTuple` from `piggybank.jar.` Download the jar file from this link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpiggybankjar.htm  and try the below approach.

**PigScript:**

```
REGISTER '/tmp/piggybank.jar';
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage() AS (hour:int, statusCode:chararray);
B = GROUP A BY (hour,statusCode);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (hour,statusCode),COUNT($1) AS cnt;
D = GROUP C BY hour;
E = FOREACH D {
                   mytuple = FOREACH C GENERATE TOTUPLE(statusCode,cnt);
                   GENERATE group,FLATTEN(BagToTuple(mytuple));
              }
STORE E INTO 'output1' USING PigStorage();
```

**Output:**

```
0   (302,2) (304,3) (403,1) (500,1)
1   (200,1) (301,1) (304,2) (400,1) (403,1) (502,5)
```

**Sample input passed to the script:**

**input**

```
0       302
0       302
0       304
0       304
0       304
0       403
0       500
1       200
1       301
1       304
1       304
1       400
1       403
1       502
1       502
1       502
1       502
1       502
```